# Given roots find the homogeneous differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following roots: $$\lambda = 0,0,\pm a, \pm a, \ \ \ \ \ a \neq 0$$
Basically I have that the equation must satisy: $\lambda^2(\lambda^2 -a^2)^2 = 0$. so after expanding, i have: $$\lambda^6 - 2a^2\lambda^4 + a^4\lambda^2 = 0.$$
Now, the solution of a homogeneos  constant coeeficient is given by $x(t) = e^{\lambda t}$. Then, we must have: 
$$e^{\lambda t}[\lambda^6 - 2a^2\lambda^4 + a^4\lambda^2] = 0,$$
notice that $x^{(6)}(t) =\lambda^6 e^{\lambda t}, \ x^{(4)}(t) =\lambda^4 e^{\lambda t}, x''(t) = \lambda^2 e^{\lambda t}$. So the Differential equation must be given by 
$$x^{(6)}(t) - 2a^2x^{(4)}(t) + a^4x''(t) = 0$$
and the solution is given by
$$x(t) = c_1 + tc_2 + c_3e^{at} + c_4e^{-at} + c_5te^{at} + c_6te^{-at}$$
Can someone verify is this procedure is Ok.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure if this was the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\pm a$ is also a repeated root, so you should actually have

$$\lambda^2 (\lambda^2 - a^2)^2 = 0$$

Looks like just a typo though. The rest of your solution is correct

Answer (score 0):

You wrote $\pm a$ twice, meaning a repeated root, so you should be starting with: $\lambda^2 (\lambda^2 - a^2)^2 = 0$. Else, all steps okay.